# group by query to select single record of maximum match found in strings from each group

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables.
table1: wp_pc_products

```
feed_product_name     id_merchant
    sony xperia c3        fkt
    nokia lumia           fkt
    samsung galaxy        fkt
    sony xperia c3        snd
    nokia lumia           snd
    samsung galaxy        snd
```

table2: wp_pc_products_merchants

```
slug     image
fkt      logo1.png
snd      logo2.png
```

The relation between these two table is, id_merchant in wp_pc_products and slug in wp_pc_products_merchants has same record but distinct in second table.

My existing query is

```
select p.feed_product_name,p.id_merchant,m.image from wp_pc_products p JOIN wp_pc_products_merchants m ON m.slug=p.id_merchant where (feed_product_name like'sony%' or feed_product_name like'%xperia%' or feed_product_name like'%c3%') and (p.price BETWEEN "629.3" and "1168.7"
```

If i use group by clause as (group by id_merchant) at the end of this query the query is not giving me the expected result.

I have tried this query as well and its working fine but same way i want in above query.

```
SELECT  wp_pc_products.*,wp_pc_products_merchants.image FROM wp_pc_products JOIN wp_pc_products_merchants ON wp_pc_products.id_merchant = wp_pc_products_merchants.slug  WHERE feed_product_name LIKE '%sony%' and feed_product_name LIKE '%xperia%' and feed_product_name LIKE '%c3%' group by id_merchant
```

My expected resutl is:

```
sony xperia c3    fkt     logo1.png
sony xperia c3    snd     logo2.png
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key for `wp_pc_products` table ?

Comment: yes i have a column id_product which is auto increment numbers

Comment: GROUP BY will return 1 row for each id_merchant. The other fields it returns should be aggregate fields, With your 2nd query if there were multiple products for each id_merchant then which one is returned is not determined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do using the technique group wise maximum http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

```
select 
wpp1.feed_product_name,
wpp1.id_merchant,
wpm.image
from wp_pc_products wpp1
join (
  select min(id_product) as id_product,id_merchant
  from wp_pc_products group by id_merchant
)wpp2 on wpp2.id_product = wpp1.id_product
join wp_pc_products_merchants wpm on wpm.slug = wpp1.id_merchant
```